# Unwanted evaluation of boolean expression in sympy

Tags: python, anaconda, boolean, sympy, piecewise

I am trying to formulate a piecewise function in sympy and then plot it, but I can't formulate the wanted function. The problem is that `(x > 0) & (x < 1)` evaluates `x > 0` to be always `True` before it can be passed to the Piecewise constructor. This can be circumvented by not setting `positive=True` in the symbols constructor, but this makes the square root simplify to `√(x^2)`, in this case i want it to simplify to `x`. I am currently using the base (root) enviroment in latest version of Anaconda Distribution on windows. The code is tested in the aforementioned enviroment with a JupyterLab notebook.

Current code:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)
f = sqrt(x**2)

f_piecewise = Piecewise((2, (x > 0) & (x < 1) ),
          ( 3 * f, (x > 1) & (x < 2) ),
          ( -3 * f, (x > 2) & (x < 3)),
          (0, True)
         )

pprint(f_piecewise)
display(f_piecewise)
plot(f_piecewise, (x, -0.01, 3.01))
```

Result from current code:

```
⎧ 2        for x < 1    
⎪                       
⎪3⋅x   for x > 1 ∧ x < 2
⎨                       
⎪-3⋅x  for x > 2 ∧ x < 3
⎪                       
⎩ 0        otherwise
```

[Latex and matplotlib output missing boolean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znwSe.png)

Expected output:

```
⎧ 2    for x > 0 ∧ x < 1
⎪                       
⎪3⋅x   for x > 1 ∧ x < 2
⎨                       
⎪-3⋅x  for x > 2 ∧ x < 3
⎪                       
⎩ 0        otherwise
```

[Latex and matplotlib expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmhB.png)

I have figured out a fix when doing this with only one boolean evaluation for example with greater then.
Faulty code:

```
test = Piecewise((f, (x > 0)),
                 (1, True) 
                )
pprint(test)
display(test)
plot(test)
```

Working code:

```
test = Piecewise((f, Gt(x, 0, evaluate=False)),
                 (1, True) 
                )
pprint(test)
display(test)
plot(test)
```

I have tried the following to get it to work with "and" but none of them worked:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
test = Piecewise((f, parse_expr("GreaterThan(x, 0, evaluate=False) & (x < 1)", {'x':x}, evaluate=False)),
                 (1, True) 
                )

test = Piecewise((f, And(GreaterThan(x, 0, evaluate=False), (x < 1), evaluate=False)),
                 (1, True) 
                )
```

Thanks to anybody taking their time to look at this :D.

Comment: Presumably there's some reason you can't just do `f = x`.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy forms the correct system of equations.
The point is that you set the symbol variable as positive. In this case, system:

```
⎧ 2        for x < 1    
⎪                       
⎪3⋅x   for x > 1 ∧ x < 2
⎨                       
⎪-3⋅x  for x > 2 ∧ x < 3
⎪                       
⎩ 0        otherwise
```

will be correct.

To get the system you expect, you need to remove the positivity constraint. The following code works.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)
f = sqrt(x**2)

f_piecewise = Piecewise((2, (x > 0) & (x < 1) ),
          ( 3 * f, (x > 1) & (x < 2) ),
          ( -3 * f, (x > 2) & (x < 3)),
          (0, True)
         )

pprint(f_piecewise)
```

This is what it returns:

```
⎧  2     for x > 0 ∧ x < 1
⎪                         
⎪3⋅│x│   for x > 1 ∧ x < 2
⎨                         
⎪-3⋅│x│  for x > 2 ∧ x < 3
⎪                         
⎩  0         otherwise
```

P.S. Note that your function is defined as zero at points 1 and 2. Use '>=' or '<=' for correct behavior. Unfortunately, these points are not reflected as 0 on the chart.